# Zendesk iOS SDK multilanguage support

Tags: ios, objective-c, zendesk

are there anyone familiar with Zendesk iOS SDK? I am trying to integrate this SDK to my iOS app and the integration was done really issue, the only problem I have currently is multi language support. My app have a view when you can change the language on the fly using this code:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:lang forKey:@"lang"]; 
[defaults synchronize];
```

It changes the lang in app successfully, but it is not changing for Zendesk View. How to change language for Zendesk Chat View also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer would be to override ZDCChatStrings bundle with your custom class, and whenever it will call for localizedStringForKey method return translation from your internal translations list. Code:

```
#import "NSBundle+Language.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface CustomBundle : NSBundle

@end

@implementation CustomBundle

- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value 
table:(NSString *)tableName
{
   return NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, g_appDelegate.lang, key);

}

@end

@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)registerBundle
{
    static dispatch_once_t tempToken;
    dispatch_once(&tempToken, ^{

        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"ZDCChatStrings" ofType: @"bundle"]];

        object_setClass(bundle, [CustomBundle class]);

    });

}

@end
```

Initialize somewhere in your AppDelegate:

```
[NSBundle registerBundle];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Localizable string in ZenDesk Api Files not your custom file. But this is Internationalization. Language change according to your phone Language.

Goto Your Projects Supporting Files. There are ZDCChatStrings.bundle and ZDCChat.bundle are there. Open ZDCChatStrings.bundle. In this you see Localizable.strings for All languages.

[image: See Screens]

Right click on strings files which you want and Open as Ascii Property List. Change strings accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I know how to change that, the problem I have  how to change the language on the fly. So I can reach that ZDCChatStrings bundle and set it to other language without being tied with iPhone global language selection.

Comment: I cant open the files as ASCII Property List do you know why?

Comment: @GaboRuiz I can't too. Any luck yet?